# Spark proxy-user not being used when creating hdfs folders on cluster secured w/ Kerberos

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark Application that is launched via spark submit. The proxy-user is set and yarn mode is being used. 
When the application is launched it correctly shows in Hue UI that the job is running as the proxy-user. 
On HDFS the .sparkStaging folder under /user/proxy-user/.sparkStaging is created (and all its contents) with the owner being the proxy-user -- all good so far.

However, once the application code executes and tries to create resources (ie. a folder named: result) under /user/proxy-user/result the owner is created by super user and not the proxy-user. This causes subsequent failures since the proxy-user now lacks correct access rights to the 'result' folder and its children.

This is being run on Cloudera 5.7 with Kerberos. I can provide more details if need be -- just didn't want to spew a long yarn (no pun intended) of irrelevant details.

Then the proxy-user looks like it cannot write to folder created by different owner. from logs:

```
    at  WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, clustername.com, executor 2): org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=anonymous, access=WRITE, inode="/user/anonymous/result345/_temporary/0":superuser:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthoriz    ationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthoriz    ationProvider.java:281)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthoriz    ationProvider.check(DefaultAuthoriz    ationProvider.java:262)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthoriz    ationProvider.check(DefaultAuthoriz    ationProvider.java:242)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthoriz    ationProvider.checkPermission(DefaultAuthoriz    ationProvider.java:169)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:152)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6590)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6572)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6524)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2758)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2676)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2561)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.cre    ate(NameNodeRpcServer.java:593)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.Authoriz    ationProviderProxyClientProtocol.cre    ate(Authoriz    ationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:111)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTransl    atorPB.cre    ate(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTransl    atorPB.java:393)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2086)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2082)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(N    ative Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInform    ation.doAs(UserGroupInform    ation.java:1693)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2080)

at sun.reflect.N    ativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(N    ative Method)
at sun.reflect.N    ativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(N    ativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.Deleg    atingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Deleg    atingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instanti    ateException(RemoteException.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCre    ate(DFSOutputStream.java:1653)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.cre    ate(DFSClient.java:1689)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.cre    ate(DFSClient.java:1624)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$7.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:448)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$7.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:444)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.cre    ate(DistributedFileSystem.java:459)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.cre    ate(DistributedFileSystem.java:387)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.cre    ate(FileSystem.java:911)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.cre    ate(FileSystem.java:804)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputForm    at.getRecordWriter(TextOutputForm    at.java:123)
at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:90)
at    org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopD    ataset$1$$anonfun$13  .apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1197)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at         java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What kind of resources you mean? table partitions ? Please provide some code snippet

Comment: @FaigB here is a code snippet `JavaRDD<String> outputRdd =
      rdd.map( ...);
    outputRdd.saveAsTextFile( getUri().getPath() );`  After successfully staging app as proxy user, the hdfs folders created by the snippet are owned by main kerberos principal.  T